# Someone can tell me what's the difference between List, Collection and Enumerable?

Tags: c#, list, collections, ienumerable, enumerable

While I do a program, sometimes I've got this doubt. I have been using `List<T>` but I haven't used the others.

I'd like to know when each one is better to use, and under what circumstances.

Comment: See the documentation.

Comment: Depends on what you are wanting to do also with List<T> Generics are awesome way of creating or making sure that something is Type Specific List is also a Collection but if you want to Enumerate thru something where you would have to pretty much design your own enumerator (Counter) IEnumerable<T> would be good to.. but then there is also foreach and for loops it just depends on what you want to do and how fast you want it done Nicholas posted some great links to explain it best..

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'm sure you can read the documentation by yourself. I'll give a short summary here:

1. `IEnumerable` is an interface that exposes an enumerator over a collection. Implement this interface if want to be able to support iteration, for example inside a `foreach` loop.
2. `Collection` is an implementation of `IEnumerable` (therefore you can iterate over it) that is generally further extended by user-defined classes that want to have collection-like behavior (i.e. use `Add`, `Remove`, `Contains`, etc.). It can also be used "as-is".
3. `List` is also an implementation of `IEnumerable` (therefore you can iterate over it) that is generally used "as-is" as a container for objects of a certain type. Uses a dynamically adjusting array in the background and is the generic equivalent of `ArrayList`.

Note that while `IEnumerable` can be both generic and non-generic, `Collection` and `List` can only be used as generic classes.

Answer (score 1):

MSDN can:

- [`List<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19.aspx)
- [`IList<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5y536ey6.aspx)
- [`ICollection<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/92t2ye13.aspx)
- [`IEnumerable<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9eekhta0.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

List is instantiable type that holds items in a linear fashion. (Edit: I'm told it's implemented with a dynamic array, rather than with a Linked List, which was just my guess).

`ICollection`/`CollectionBase` and `IEnumerable` aren't directly instantiable types.

`CollectionBase`/`ICollection` is a base class/interface that is inherited/implemented by any class that considers itself a collection and holds multiple items. `CollectionBase`/`ICollection` also allows you to pass around collections without knowing their implementation.

`IEnumerable`is also a interface that provides methods for iterating over the collection. `IEnumerable` basically lets you use `foreach` loops on the collection. You can use the interface methods directly to get some C++ style iterators going, but the `foreach` loop is less error prone.

Comment: List uses a dynamic array, not a linked list.

Comment: @Digitlworld: In the strange world of Microsoft's CLR team, lists are not actually lists in the CS sense: The backing store for both `SCG.List<T>` and `SC.List` is an array that grows dynamically by allocation and copy. ICollection and IEnumerable aren't types at all: they are interfaces.

Comment: In C# land, it was my understanding that interfaces, abstract classes and normal classes were all `Type`s. Reflection-based instances of their definition are all acceptable values for `Type`.

Comment: @Digitlworld interfaces are not base classes. ICollection is only an interface, likewise IEnumerable.

Comment: I posted the answer a little too quick, and as a result wasn't specific enough. I apologize. :)

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the definitions of the three (see below) you will notice that `List` implements `Enumerable` and `ICollection` and `ICollection` implements `IEnumerable`.  More clearly:

`List` is *CLASS* which can store a variable number of items of the same type plus the functionality specified by the other two interfaces.

`ICollection` is an interface which specifies a generic way to manipulate collections. NOTE: this is an interface and thus is NOT capable of being instantiated.

`IEnumerable` is an interface which specifies a means of iterating over a collection.  NOTE: this is an interface and thus is NOT capable of being instantiated.

[List](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19.aspx)

Represents a strongly typed list of objects that can be accessed by index. Provides methods to search, sort, and manipulate lists.

```
public class List<T> : IList<T>, ICollection<T>, 
IEnumerable<T>, IList, ICollection, IEnumerable
```

[ICollection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/92t2ye13.aspx)

Defines methods to manipulate generic collections.

```
public interface ICollection<T> : IEnumerable<T>, 
IEnumerable
```

[IEnumerable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9eekhta0.aspx)

Exposes the enumerator, which supports a simple iteration over a collection of a specified type.

```
public interface IEnumerable<out T> : IEnumerable
```